# Selected features checkbox in graphical modeler

Tags: qgis-modeler

I'd like to know how can i add the checkbox of the selected features in the input layer of the Graphical Modeler of QGIS. Is it available this feature?
For example, like this checkbox of a classical qgis geoprocessing:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use *Vector Feature* as input instead of *Vector Layer*. It is almost the same but you have the "Selected features only" checkbox in addition.